# How to launch the cell associated with many tags?

Tags: syntax, cells

Consider some section `Section 1` and its subsection `Subsection 1`.

I want to associate the whole cell with `Section 1` with the tag Sec.1, while for `Subsection 1` (selecting only the corresponding cell) I want to add the tag "Subsec.1". I.e., `Section 1` would be associated with "Sec. 1", while `Subsection 1` - with "Sec. 1" and "Subsec. 1":

[image]

Could you please tell me how to launch the cell associated with "Sec. 1" and "Subsec. 1" (i.e. `Subsection 1`)?

The code I found,

```
(NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellTags]; 
   SelectionEvaluate[nb]) & /@ {"Sec. 1", "Subsec. 1"}
```

does not do this but launches first the cell associated with "Sec. 1" and second the cell associated with "Subsec. 1".

The "hand-made" code

```
NotebookFind[nb, {"Sec. 1", "Subsec. 1"}, All, CellTags]
```

does not work at all:

> $Failed

Although it runs for separate tags "Sec. 1" and "Subsec. 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
NotebookLocate["Subsec. 1"];
subsecCells = SelectedCells[];
NotebookLocate["Sec. 1"];
secCells = SelectedCells[];
SelectionMove[First[Intersection[secCells, subsecCells]], All, Cell];
SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Could bundle that up into a function that took a list of tags as an argument. Not sure how you want to handle error/edge condtions.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you think, why the standard choice {"Sec. 1", "Subsec. 1"} does not work? I have checked, this syntax is documented in Mathematica (on `CellTags` page)... This is Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation for CellTags and for NotebookFind, and nothing that I've read suggests that using a list as the second argument to NotebookFind should work as you expect.

Comment: The page contains the example `CreateDocument[{TextCell["abc", "Text", CellTags -> "tag1"], 
   TextCell["def", "Text", CellTags -> {"tag1", "tag2"}]}, 
  ShowCellTags -> True];` where `CellTags ->{"tag1","tag2"}` looks like the thing. But I may be wrong.

Comment: I mean, that's a completely different function.

Comment: You can use CellTags as an option to TextCell. That'll set the CellTags option for the TextCell, which seems reasonable. NotebookFind just wasn't designed to look for a list of cell tags. In the documentation for NotebookFind it says "data [the second argument] can be a string, box expression, or a complete cell".

Comment: FWIW, I'm not particularly experienced with front-end programming, so it's entirely possible that there's some nuance here that I'm missing. Maybe there is a more "organic" way to use NotebookFind to search for a list of cell tags. If there is, I don't know what it is, and it would contradict my interpretation of the documentation.